# `dplyr::summarise` does not accept external functions

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the follow dataset:

```
dataset=structure(list(var1 = c(28.5627505742013, 22.8311421908438, 95.2216156944633, 
43.9405107684433, 97.11211245507, 48.4108281508088, 77.1804554760456, 
27.1229329891503, 69.5863061584532, 87.2112890332937), var2 = c(32.9009465128183, 
54.1136392951012, 69.3181485682726, 70.2100433968008, 44.0986660309136, 
62.8759404085577, 79.4413498230278, 97.4315509572625, 62.2505457513034, 
76.0133410431445), var3 = c(89.6971945464611, 67.174579706043, 
37.0924087055027, 87.7977314218879, 29.3221596442163, 37.5143952667713, 
62.6237869635224, 71.3644423149526, 95.3462834469974, 27.4587387405336
), var4 = c(41.5336912125349, 98.2095112837851, 80.7970978319645, 
91.1278881691396, 66.4086666144431, 69.2618868127465, 67.7560870349407, 
71.4932355284691, 21.345994155854, 31.1811877787113), var5 = c(33.9312525652349, 
88.1815139763057, 98.4453701227903, 25.0217059068382, 41.1195872165263, 
37.0983888953924, 66.0217586159706, 23.8814191706479, 40.9594196081161, 
79.7632974945009), var6 = c(39.813664201647, 80.6405956856906, 
30.0273275375366, 34.6203793399036, 96.5195455029607, 44.5830867439508, 
78.7370151281357, 42.010761089623, 23.0079878121614, 58.0372223630548
), kmeans = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "kmeans"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And the follow function:

```
myfun<-function(x){
  c(sum(x),mean(x),sd(x))
}
```

With `dplyr::summarise` only, the result is ok:

```
library(tidyverse)

my1<-dataset%>%
  summarise_if(.,is.numeric,.funs=funs(sum,mean,sd))
```

But, with `myfun` doesn't work:

```
my2<-dataset%>%
  summarise_if(.,is.numeric,.funs=funs(myfun))
```

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Column `var1` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 3

What's the problem?

Comment: Could you provide an example showing `summarise` working? Excuse my ignorance, how does one return three values into one column? What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: The problem is setting several values to a single column. I don't know how time consuming it is, but you could run these functions separately.

Comment: Just examine the difference between `funs(sum, mean, sd)` and `funs(c(sum, mean, sd))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this approach, Your approach will not yield the correct result as there it is not able to wrap two values returned by your custom function in a single cell, to circumvent the problem, I used `enframe` with `list` in the custom function:

```
library(tidyverse)

myfun<-function(x){
    return(list(enframe(c('sum' = sum(x),'mean' = mean(x),'sd' = sd(x)))))
}
```

For example with `mtcars` data:

```
my2<-mtcars%>%
summarise_at(c('mpg','drat'), function(x) myfun(x)) %>% 
unnest() %>% 
select(-name1) %>% 
set_names(nm = c('name', 'mpg', 'drat'))
```

it will yield:

```
  name        mpg        drat
1  sum 642.900000 115.0900000
2 mean  20.090625   3.5965625
3   sd   6.026948   0.5346787
```

Also, there is one alternate way in which you can try solving it using `purrr`.

For example:

```
f <- function(x,...){
    list('mean' = mean(x, ...),'sum' = sum(x, ...))
}

mtcars %>% 
select(mpg, drat) %>% 
map_dfr(~ f(.x, na.rm=T), .id ="Name") %>% 
data.frame()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are applying this function

```
dataset%>% summarise_if(is.numeric,.funs=funs(sum,mean,sd))
```

You are applying three different function (`sum`, `mean` and `sd`) which is applied to all columns individually. So every column which is numeric these function would be applied to them. Here we have got three different function returning three values.

Regarding your function, I think what you were trying to do was

```
myfun<-function(x){
  c(sum(x),mean(x),sd(x))
}
```

Now , when this function is applied to one column it returns you three values, so here one function is returning you three values instead.

```
myfun(dataset$var1)
#[1] 597.17994  59.71799  29.03549
```

As @NelsonGon mentioned in the comments, you are trying to store three values in single column. You could return them as list as @Pkumar showed or some variation of `do` also would help you achieve that. If you break down the functions and make three functions separately, it would work the same way as you have shown earlier.

```
myfun1 <- function(x) sum(x)
myfun2  <- function(x) mean(x)
myfun3 <- function(x) sd(x)

dataset %>% summarise_if(is.numeric,.funs=funs(myfun1,myfun2,myfun3))
```

Answer (score 1):

it's not the most elegant way, but if your external function is just a list of other functions, maybe you can just use a list for your functions:

```
myfun_ls <- list(sum,mean,sd)
my2<-dataset%>%
  summarise_if(.,is.numeric,.funs=myfun_ls)
```